# Image didn't load in JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, file, java-io

I have a JPanel name "imagePanel" and a button name "browseBtn". All contained in a JFrame class. When pressing the browseBtn, a file chooser will open up and after choosing a PNG image file, the image will appear directly in the imagePanel.

This is the action event for the browseBtn

```
private void browseBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
      JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        if (accept(file)) {
            try {
                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
                JLabel l = new JLabel(image);
                imagePanel.add(l);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error reading file !");
            }
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Choose png file only !");
        } 
    }

}                                         

public boolean accept(File file) {
    return file.isDirectory() || file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".png");
}
```

I have choose the correct .png file but i don't understand why the image didn't show up in the imagePanel. Can you guy explain on that ?
Cheers.

Comment: 1) For starters, `new ImageIcon(file.getPath());` should best be `new ImageIcon(file);` 2) Dynamicall adding components is tricky. I suggest instead to add the `JLabel` at startup, then simply call `l.setIcon(..)`.

Comment: but it will throw an error :"no suitable constructor found for ImageIcon(File)" when using ImageIcon(file)

Comment: D'Oh! My (and Oracle's) bad. When something is supposed to represent a `File` path, they ***should*** offer a constructor for a `File` (damn it!).

Comment: yeah,  but i made it. I replace by using Label instead of Panel, it worked perfectly. Thanks anyway, sir ! There is only one more problem when I choose a picture with the larger resolution than the frame, it seems a little big, how can i control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid creating new objects everytime you want to display your image, imagine if you change it 5 times, you're creating 5 times an object while you display only one !

Like said in the comments, your best shot would be to create your label when you create your panel, add it to said panel, then simply change the icon of this label when you load your image.

```
        browseBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                if (accept(file)) {
                    try {
                        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(file.getPath());
                        label.setIcon(image);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error reading file !");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Choose png file only !");
                } 
            }
        }

        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory() || file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".png");
        }


    });
```

Assuming label is the reference to said JLabel, created on components initialisation.

Comment: I made it, thank you, but when i choose the picture with the larger resolution than the frame, it seems a little big, how can i control it ?

Comment: There are a variety of options. The simplest is to put the label in a scroll-pane. More complex is to resize the image. Even more complex is to resize the image to the available space, then resizing it if the user drags the GUI larger or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Or you might try this :

```
browseBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
  int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
  if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
  if (accept(file)) {
  try {
   ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new   ImageIcon(file.getPath()).getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20,    Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)); //resizing
   label.setIcon(imageIcon);

  /*try { // or try this
     InputStream inStream =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file.getPath());
     BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inStream);
     Image rimg = img.getScaledInstance(width, height,  Image.SCALE_STANDARD);
     label.setIcon(rimg);
    } catch (IOException e) {}*/
  } catch (Exception ex) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error reading file !");}
  } else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Choose png file  only  !");} 
 }
 }
  public boolean accept(File file) {
   return file.isDirectory() || file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".png");
  }
 });
```